# Multiple submit in knockout

Tags: javascript, forms, knockout.js, form-submit

We have a [`submit` binding in knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html), however we can use it only on **whole form**, so in a case of **multiple submit** buttons, they all trigger same binding. I'd like differ action for each one, but idk how to differ which one has been clicked, eg.:

HTML:

```
<form data-bind="submit: save">
    <input type=submit name=save value=Save>
    <input type=submit name=saveAndClose value="Save & close">
</form>
```

VM:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.save = function (form) {
        var clicked = 'how to find out?';

        if (clicked === 'save') {
            // save
        } else if (clicked === 'saveAndClose') {
            // save
            // close
        }
    };
};
```

Yea, I can use `click` binding on each submit, but then there's no `form` element available, yea - I can obtain it by different way, but maybe you know better solution.

Do you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Overload `submit` binding to allow use it on any element.

JSFiddle: [Knockout submit binding applicable onto any button](https://jsfiddle.net/hejdav/yeuumdma/2/) *(uses jQuery)*

Binding overload:

```
var overridden = ko.bindingHandlers.submit.init;
var $clickedButton;
ko.bindingHandlers.submit.init = function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var $form = $(element);

    if ($form.prop('tagName') !== 'FORM') {
        var $button = $form;
        $form = $form.closest('form');

        if ($form.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('Submit binding can be used only in forms');
        }

        $button.on('click', function () {
            $clickedButton = $button;
        });

        var formHandler = function () {
            return function () {
                if ($clickedButton === $button) {
                    return valueAccessor().apply(this, arguments);
                }
                return false;
            };
        };

        overridden.apply(this, [$form[0], formHandler].concat([].splice.call(arguments, 2)));
    } else {
        overridden.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = {
    submitA: function () {
        alert('A');
    },
    submitB: function () {
        alert('B');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<form method=post>
  <input type=submit data-bind="submit: submitA" value=A>
  <input type=submit data-bind="submit: submitB" value=B>
</form>
```

Comment: whoever downvoted, I would be very appreciative if you explain, what's wrong with my solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is to use a click binding on each input and pass a `$element` variable as a parameter. As such:

```
<form>
    <input type=submit name=save data-bind="click: save.bind(null, $element)" value=Save>
    <input type=submit name=saveAndClose data-bind="click: save.bind(null, $element)" value="Save & close">
</form>
```

`bind` in javascript creates a new function with a specified this (null) and parameter ($element) in this case. Therefore, it is easy to obtain a form element, and determine which input was clicked:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.save = function (el) {
        var clicked = el.getAttribute('name');
        var form = el.parentElement;

            console.log(clicked, form)
        if (clicked === 'save') {
            // save
        } else if (clicked === 'saveAndClose') {
            // save
            // close
        }
    };
};
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhjypj7z/)

Note however, that this method is markup dependent, if the inputs are not direct children of the form element, you may need to find another method to get the form element itself instead of `parentElement`

Comment: I didn't know there's an `$element` context available, so thank u. I'll wait few days more if some more elegant solution will appear, but if not, I'll use your approach. Fyi I'd love if there was a `submit` binding directly on submit input.

Comment: another way would be to write a custom binding for the form element